# ControlsFX MaskerPane http won't show

Tags: http, javafx, pane, controlsfx

I want to show the MaskerPane from ControlsFx if a network request is executed. It should be an indicator if the request is still running. Also i want to run the network request in the background so the window doesn't freeze.

```
private void search(String searchTerm, boolean tvShow){

    masker.setVisible(true);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Callable<List<String>> callable = new Callable<List<String>>() {

        @Override
        public List<String> call() throws Exception {
            return tmdbWrapper.search(searchTerm, tvShow);
        }

    };
    Future<List<String>> future = executor.submit(callable);
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        System.out.println(future.get().toString());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("finally");
        masker.setVisible(false);
    }
```

The problem is, that the MaskerPane doesn't show until the request is finished.

tmdbWrapper is a Wrapper for the tmdb Api.

If I would do something like this

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public synchronized void run(){
        masker.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(tmdbWrapper.search(searchTerm, tvShow));
            masker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }.start();
```

it would work. Because it would be bad coding style and won't be an FX-application Thread I don't want it to do it like that.